# Extracting unique values from array

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I performed MorphologicalComponents on an image, and from there used SelectComponents to filter out my desired components. Is there a way to extract out the unique values from the entire array? i.e. get a list of the labelled component values

I tried using DeleteDuplicates, but that only works on a list, and also tried using Select with a search criteria #>0, but that didn't work out as well.

Thank you!

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten`?

Comment: That works, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, you gave the answer yourself: "but that only works on a list" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was given by Henrik:

```
DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten@array.
```

Thank you!